# Why does not the pointerPressed method work in this situation?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, alcatel-ot

I created a java class which extends CustomItem :

```
package view;

import com.sun.lwuit.Dialog;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;

public class Thumb extends CustomItem {
    private Image theImage;
    public Thumb(Image photo)
    {
        super("");
        theImage = photo;
    }
    private Image createThumbnail(Image image) {
        int sourceWidth = image.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = image.getHeight();
        int thumbWidth = 64;
        int thumbHeight = -1;

        if (thumbHeight == -1) {
            thumbHeight = thumbWidth * sourceHeight / sourceWidth;
        }

        Image thumb = Image.createImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
        Graphics g = thumb.getGraphics();

        for (int y = 0; y < thumbHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < thumbWidth; x++) {
                g.setClip(x, y, 1, 1);
                int dx = x * sourceWidth / thumbWidth;
                int dy = y * sourceHeight / thumbHeight;
                g.drawImage(image, x - dx, y - dy, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
            }
        }
        Image immutableThumb = Image.createImage(thumb);
        return immutableThumb;
    }
    protected int getMinContentHeight() {
        return 64 * theImage.getHeight() / theImage.getWidth();
    }

    protected int getMinContentWidth() {
        return 64;
    }

    protected int getPrefContentHeight(int width) {
        return 64 * theImage.getHeight() / theImage.getWidth();
    }

    protected int getPrefContentWidth(int height) {
        return 64;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g, int w, int h) {
        Image transformImage = createThumbnail(theImage);
        g.drawImage(transformImage, 0, 0, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
    }
    protected void pointerPressed(int x, int y)
    {
        Dialog.show("Info", "I clicked the screen !", "ok", null);
    }
}
```

And in a Form I append some items created from this CustomItem :

```
fcDir = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDirectory+"/");
            if (fcDir.exists()) {
                filelist = fcDir.list("*", false);
                while (filelist.hasMoreElements()) {
                    fileName = (String) filelist.nextElement();
                    vPhotoNames.addElement(new String(fileName));
                    FileConnection fcFile = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDirectory+"/"+fileName);
                    // creation customitem
                    this.append(new Thumb(Image.createImage(fcFile.openInputStream())));
                    fcFile.close();
                }
            }
            fcDir.close();
```

When I launch the application , then :
1) the cursor cannot be moved by means of the arrow keys ( the device is Alcatel OT-806D ) , nor by means of touching the screen.
2) when I try to click on an image then nothing happens , although the Dialog should appear !

So why do these problems arise ?

Comment: I noticed that the cursor cannot be moved when I click on an image which has already got focus. But the focus can be moved if I do not click on any focus-gained image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show a LWUIT dialog from a MIDP CustomItem, that is not officially supported and is bound to fail in many creative ways. You need to either use LWUIT or use LCDUI at any given moment.